# How to capture/view Google App Script usage in Google API Console

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api-console

How can usage of Google App Script libraries like GmailApp, CalendarApp, and PropertiesService be tracked through the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com)?

While Google App Script projects do show up inside the API console, none of them show any activity when selected. I understand that individual Google APIs need to be enabled for a project in order for their usage to be visible in the API console, but none of the App Script APIs seem to be available in the list Google APIs to choose from.

My only guess is that Google App Script usage cannot in fact be tracked through the Google API Console, which is a shame since many users seem to hit their app script quota limits and would benefit from the ability to track and visualize their script's resource usage.

Comment: You cannot track it. You can catch these errors and know when they occur though and tweak the scripts accordingly. That what we have to live with for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that you cannot track the usage of individual libraries of Google App Script in the Google Developer Console except for the MailApp. The MailApp has a method of [`getRemainingDailyQuota()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getRemainingDailyQuota()) that returns the number of remaining emails a user can send for the rest of the day. You can check in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) the different quotas and limitations that you can do with the Apps script. I also suggest you to make a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?) about this issue.